# findstr error, possible format error?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ut9.png

Tried to run as admin, tried windows 8 and 10, i checked my environment variables and C:\windows\system32; is there

The only thing i can think of is that utf-8 code with ansi code will cause a error maybe?

What can i do?

here is the code, i think its too long to paste here
https://mega.nz/#!nVExWRgb!vH7rM5HwGlDQl_ZN_CDUlmaPulZK_ysdLwlTZy74Zyw

EDIT:

here is the broken code as suggested:

```
:scan32
cls
echo Your computer is being scanned, please wait.
del files.txt>nul
echo.>>files.txt
rhash --sha256 --recursive --skip-ok --output=files.txt --log=log_file.txt --accept=exe,dll,sys,scr %systemdrive%
del output.txt>nul
echo.>>output.txt
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /G:Database.dll files.txt') do del "%%a" & echo %%a>>output.txt
cls
echo scan done, here is a list of files found and deleted.
pause
start output.txt
cls
```

goto :if

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question should not rely on external sites and force us to go through your whole code.

Comment: I added some of the broken code

Comment: I assume you have confirmed that it is added to System Variables (Path) .. if you add it remember to restart cmd prompt.

Comment: I did, i wrote that in the thread.

Comment: You may have a variable called `path` in your batch file.  Or you manipulated the path variable incorrectly.  I checked, yes, that's the problem.  Use a different variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses a variable called `path` and that is a system variable which holds the location of all system files.

Just use a different name in all places that you used `path`